# What does 'before effects are applied' mean in the description of the ranger's Foe Slayer feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger

I'm playing a ranger in my current campaign. I'm confused about one thing in the description of the 20th-level feature, Foe Slayer. It says that the extra to-hit or damage bonus from my Wisdom modifier can be designated before or after the roll but before effects are applied.

My question relates to the phrase 'before effects are applied'. Does that mean before I know if it's a hit or miss? If so, why designate before or after the roll?

My DM ruled that I have to designate it before I know if it's a hit or miss; obviously, what the DM says goes, and I'm not going to fight him on it. I just want to know how other people interpret it, because honestly, the wording is a bit more obscure than other hard and fast rules.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your DM has the right of it. The way it is worded is designed to make it clear that the player can choose when to apply the benefit. The only limitation is that the player must make the decision to apply the modifier before the DM tells you if it would be a hit/miss or the effect of the damage dealt.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It makes sense. I'm just going to have to talk with him about how quickly he announces hits or misses. It becomes such an automatic thing when DMing to try to keep the battle rolling that I don't think he realizes maybe I wanted to use my Wisdom modifier there.

Comment: Or, you could help the DM out by announcing that you have that special feature *before making the roll*. This way, the DM knows to allow you some time to decide after the roll, and you also help out by taking some of the task of having to remember PC capabilities from the DM. ;)

Comment: I think you're over estimating the size of our group. We have 3 pcs including me. Announcing before every time I roll would be a bit much. Still in a large group where it could be 15 minutes before your next turn in combat I could see where it would be needed. Nah our communication is pretty good I'm not worried.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the previous answer, as do [some others](https://reddit.com/r/dndnext/comments/3161m1). I see the following chain of steps:

1. An action is declared: "Alice attacks Bob with advantage"
2. before roll:  "Carol uses Protection to cancel advantage"
3. The die is rolled: numerical value
4. before outcome: "Alice uses her Bardic Inspiration die"
5. The outcome is determined: semi-boolean value (hit, miss, crit, etc)
6. after outcome, before result: "Bob casts Shield"
7. The outcome is re-determined: "sorry Bob, it's still a hit"
8. after outcome, before result: Eve considers a reaction here, but declines
9. The damage is rolled: numerical value(s)
10. after result: "Bob wishes he had saved his reaction for Stone's Endurance"
11. The damage is subtracted from Bob's hit points.

I would say "the effect" is the attack outcome in step 5, and its application (what happens as a result of a hit or miss) is the damage roll in step 9, therefore "before the effect is applied" is step 6 & 8, like Shield.

**TMI;DR** *("Too Many Ideas, Distracting the Readers")*

- Which moment is "any effects of the roll are applied"?
  Is it:

1. "the outcome is determined" (but still mutable)?
2. "the hit (or miss) really occurs"?
3. "the final effect (damage) really occurs"?
4. some other moment entirely?

- Is there any official, semi-official, or pseudo-official rules justification for either view?

Comment: The description says *You can choose to use this feature before or after the roll, but before any effects of the roll are applied*. The effects of the attack roll is hit, miss or critical, hence the WIS mod has to be added **before** the DM says if the attack succeeded or not: in the case above, between 4 and 5. The spell [*Shield*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield) says that you can cast it after *you know that you are hit*. The WIS mod can be added also to damage roll: you can add the modifier **before** knowing if the damage killed or not the creature you are attacking, for example.

Comment: wouldn't it be step 10, not 9, since you can react to the damage after it's rolled but before it's *applied* yet?